# Python test for nested json - list index out of range error

Tags: python

I'm trying to see if a key called 'AccessKeyId' exists in the output of a boto3 command.

I am getting this error:

```
  File "aws_iam_rotate_keys.py", line 76, in delete_access_key
    key2 =  response['AccessKeyMetadata'][1]['AccessKeyId']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code that generates the error:

```
user_name = str(input("Enter a user name: "))
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_access_keys')
for response in paginator.paginate(UserName=user_name):
    print("Raw response: ", response) 
    if 'AccessKeyId' and 'AccessKeyMetadata[0]':
        key1 =  response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['AccessKeyId']
        print("Key 1: ", key1)
    if 'AccessKeyId' and 'AccessKeyMetadata[1]':
        key2 =  response['AccessKeyMetadata'][1]['AccessKeyId']
```

This is the contents of a 'response':

```
 {'AccessKeyMetadata': [{'UserName': 'bluethundr', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAJNYZQ2U5LGE6ZRWQ', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 25, 17, 33, 40, tzinfo=tzutc())}], 'IsTruncated': False, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '6b3e8952-4f27-11e9-af5a-356bad8d4700', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '6b3e8952-4f27-11e9-af5a-356bad8d4700', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '558', 'date': 'Mon, 25 Mar 2019 17:57:13 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I perform this if test correctly?

In this response there can be either one or 2 keys. I want to write an if test that covers both possibilities.

If there are 2 keys the response looks like this and the code doesn't break:

```
 {'AccessKeyMetadata': [{'UserName': 'bluethundr', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAJNYZQ2U5LGE6ZRWQ', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 25, 17, 33, 40, tzinfo=tzutc())}, {'UserName': 'bluethundr', 'AccessKeyId': 'AKIAJVNDVTUVFZHWSRSA', 'Status': 'Active', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 25, 18, 8, 51, tzinfo=tzutc())}], 'IsTruncated': False, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '16957e66-4f29-11e9-b7dc-7fcb6d606368', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '16957e66-4f29-11e9-b7dc-7fcb6d606368', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '771', 'date': 'Mon, 25 Mar 2019 18:09:09 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Comment: Well, it seems your `AccessKeyMetaData` key only has a list of length `1`, so trying to access index `[1]` (i.e. 2nd index) gives you an `IndexError`... The bigger problem is your condition however.  What exactly are you trying to test? Because the string `AccessKeyId` and `AccessKeyMetadata[1]` will always evaluate to `True` for both.

Comment: `if 'AccessKeyId' and 'AccessKeyMetadata[1]'` is checking the truthiness of strings? What's the purpose of that?

Comment: Yes I am checking the truthiness of the strings. The list can contain either 1 or 2 keys. It varies depending on the user. I need to write a test that sees if 1 or 2 keys are there.

Comment: If you are trying to test for the `AccessKeyId` whether it exists, you should be doing `if 'AccessKeyId' in response['AccessKeyMetadata']:` instead.  If you want to test for the particular index, you need to check for `response['AccessKeyMetadata']` not just the string `'AccessKeyMetadata'`.  Your code is not doing what you think it does.  Any time you test for a string that is not an empty string `''` it will *always* evaluate to `True`.  You should be testing against your data, not a piece of string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checks in the `if` clauses are a bit confusing. You're checking for a non-empty string, which will always return `True`.

To keep it as close as possible to your current code, here's how you should do it:

```py
user_name = str(input("Enter a user name: "))
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_access_keys')
for response in paginator.paginate(UserName=user_name):
    print("Raw response: ", response) 
    if len(response['AccessKeyMetadata']) and 'AccessKeyId' in response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0].keys():
        key1 =  response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['AccessKeyId']
        print("Key 1: ", key1)
    if len(response['AccessKeyMetadata']) > 1 and 'AccessKeyId' in response['AccessKeyMetadata'][1].keys():
        key2 =  response['AccessKeyMetadata'][1]['AccessKeyId']
```

Comment: @bluethundr Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your check

```
if 'AccessKeyId' and 'AccessKeyMetadata[0]':
```

is a check that simply tests these constant strings. Running this code in the console returns:

```
>>> 'AccessKeyId' and 'AccessKeyMetadata[0]'
'AccessKeyMetadata[0]'
```

I suppose you want to test the response object instead:

```
# if response is a string and not yet parsed:
# response = json.loads(response)
# if it is already parsed, go on

# .get() with a default return value [] won't raise a KeyError
# or check with:
# if 'AccessKeyMetadata' in response
meta_data = response.get('AccessKeyMetadata', [])
if len(meta_data) == 1:
    key1 = meta_data[0].get('AccessKeyId', None)
elif len(meta_data) > 1:
    key2 = meta_data[1].get('AccessKeyId', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that response, `AccessKeyMetadata` is a list of one item, therefore index 1 is out of range.

Comment: Yes I know. The list can contain either one or two keys. How can I write a test that covers both possibilities?

Comment: Look at the length of the list, and if it's 1, don't try to access the second item.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statements are not doing what you think they're doing.
For example:

```
if 'AccessKeyMetadata'
```

should be:

```
if response['AccessKeyMetadata']
```